# How do I connect to cockroachDB through JDBC from logstash output plugin?

Tags: jdbc, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file, cockroachdb

I am using logstash to create a pipeline from Postgres to CockroachDB. Below is the config.

The input plugin(source is postgres) is working fine. But I am unable to establish a connection in the output plugin(cockroachDB) using JDBC. I am facing the below error.

```
JDBC - Connection is not valid. Please check connection string or that your JDBC endpoint is available. {:level=>:error, :file=>"logstash/outputs/jdbc.rb", :line=>"154", :method=>"setup_and_test_pool!"}
```

Destination(cockroachDB) is open for connection at the specified ip and port.

As cockroachDB JDBC connection string is very similar to postgres, I tried the below connection strings, and still the same error.

```
jdbc:postgresql://host/database
jdbc:postgresql://host/database?sslmode=disable
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?sslmode=disable
```

How do I connect to cockroachDB through JDBC from logstash output plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Your JDBC connection strings are OK.

Do not forget with JDBC the driver must be registered beforehand. You can do this either with `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` before your first JDBC class or invoke `java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());` before you create your connection. Perhaps you forgot to register the driver?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, this should be working now. The [problem was that JDBC's `isValid()` method was failing due to CockroachDB failing to prepare empty statements](https://github.com/theangryangel/logstash-output-jdbc/issues/53#issuecomment-242997716), which has since [been fixed in CockroachDB](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/9518).